# click event on tab that is disabled in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, tabs

I have JTabbedPane with 5 tabs in it. Tab at position 2,3 and 5 are disabled. I want to show a JDialog on click of this disabled tabs. I tried adding mouse listener and change listener but nothing worked for me. With mouse click method I can get that tab is clicked but not able to identify particular which tab is clicked. How to get click event on tab that is disabled in JTabbedPane?

Here is what I tried:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test tab pane click");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
                JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
                panel1.add(new JLabel("HI1"));
                tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", panel1);
                JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
                panel2.add(new JLabel("HI2"));
                tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", panel2);
                JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
                panel3.add(new JLabel("HI3"));
                tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 3", panel3);
                JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
                panel4.add(new JLabel("HI4"));
                tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 4", panel4);
                JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();
                panel3.add(new JLabel("HI5"));
                tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 5", panel5);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setSize(500, 200);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                // disable 2nd, 3rd and 5th tab.
                tabbedPane.setEnabledAt(1, false);
                tabbedPane.setEnabledAt(2, false);
                tabbedPane.setEnabledAt(4, false);

                tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("I'm not called for disabled tabs.");
                    }
                });
                tabbedPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("I'm called for disabled tabs, but not able to know which tab is clicked.");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`With mouse click method I can get that tab is clicked but not able to identify particular which tab is clicked.`

You can make use of `JTabbedPane`'s `indexAtLocation(int, int)` method (`MouseEvent` has `getX()` and `getY()`), which tells you the index of the tab containing the given location.

Comment: For the first point it returns JFrame reference. But second points works, Thanks :)